# Why my maschine1 take 40 jobs, when only 20 jobs should arrive?

Tags: anylogic

[I have built one model with enter, the 20 jobs are based on a DB to get the sequencens of the jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dArYi.png)

Somehow, if run the model, i only get a maschine1 40 jobs. i don't know why this happen.

I have a nextmachine function that works with a counter inside my Job agent and a collection of ArrayList with Element class Other: Enter associated with the name of my Enters(same name in DB) :

```
if(agent.counter>=enterBlocks.size())
    end.take(agent); // take the agent to the exit
else{
    Enter enter=findFirst(enterBlocks,e->e.getName().equals(agent.col_machineSequence.get(agent.counter)));
    enter.take(agent); //take the agent to the correct station
    agent.counter++; //update your counter
}
```

My Parameters are String Parameters an on startup of my Job agent i use:

```
for (String param : List.of("op1","op2","op3","op4","op5")) {
    col_machineSequence.add(getParameter(param));
}
```

Can someone tell me why i get 40 jobs shown at maschine1 (enter-Element).

I thought it has to do with my counter, thats start at 0 but if i change the counter value i don't get 20 jobs.

I didn't found any post on SOF or Anylogic Help, that could explain me the issue.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. Some tips on using this platform: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: thanks benjamin, i will try to specify my Question.

Comment: It is very hard to "tell you why" with some screenshots and a bit of code. You need to put on your "Sherlock Holmes" head and investigate bit by bit. What if you only send 1 agent, what if you change the String input list, what if... find the root cause and in 95% of the cases, you will be able to fix this yourself :) (Hard for anyone else to play Sherlock :) )

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, i could solve my Problem! You was right, sometimes you have to investigate bit by bit :D

Comment: pls post the answer here as well, this helps future users with similar issues :)

Comment: Sure, i had to change the counter value to 1 because the function had a counter update too and that was the reason maschine1 counted the double value.